# Get a specific glyph from Delphi VCL Style

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I want to get at a specific bitmap from a VCL style - and set it as an image on a button - it is actually the help question mark. In the Bitmap Style Editor is is the btnHelp image, from the Form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a Visual element (glyph) from a VCL Style you must use the  `GetElementDetails` and the `TCustomStyleServices.DrawElement` procedure.

Try this sample

```
uses
  Vcl.Themes;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LDetails : TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  //Get the detailsfor the HelpButton
  LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twHelpButtonNormal);
  //Draw the the element in the canvas.
  StyleServices.DrawElement(TPaintBox(Sender).Canvas.Handle, LDetails, TPaintBox(Sender).ClientRect);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I could get the unthemed icons, but not the themed one.