# Extract icon from VCL style and use as menu icon, not working for all styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I need to replace a main menu icon (specifically, the help icon) with an icon from the current VCL style being used (our application shows this icon on the right hand side of the menu-bar, and it looks odd to use an icon that is pulled from a resource file which doesn't match the active theme).

I can't find a way of extracting an image from the style and then using that as the menu icon. Has anyone done this?

---

Update: This isn't drawing the styled icon (as per previous question), but getting the main menu to have the themed icon (rather than an unthemed resource or a standard icon).

---

Update2: If I get the style element and draw that into a TBitmap, it works when the Style is 'Windows', but not for other themes.

```
  // Need to populate the image from the theme
  LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twHelpButtonNormal);

  bitmap := Tbitmap.Create;
  bitmap.Height := 16;
  bitmap.width := 16;
  StyleServices.DrawElement(bitmap.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);

  HelpMenuItem.Bitmap := bitmap;
```

The element is there, but it has no icon.

[image: Default Windows style]
[image: With a style]

Comment: Did you not ask the same question just recently: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41201617/2292722

Comment: See update, not the same question - it's just very similar sounding.

Comment: So, is it different to draw a styled icon on a button vs menu item? Just asking.

Comment: @TomBrunberg or, for that matter, onto a temp `TBitmap` that is then assigned to the button or menu as needed.

Comment: I'll try the above suggestion.

Comment: See the above update, where it works in one style, but not in others

Comment: I now this is 12 months old, but I have since tried it with Delphi 10.2.2 and get the same behaviour, it only works when the style is "Windows".